Audacity: Record both outgoing and incoming sound of a Zoom session
I want to use Audacity to record team meetings we have in Zoom. I need (of course) to record both outgoing sound (what I am saying) and incoming sound (what all the other participants are saying).
I am using Audacity (my current version: 3.0.0) on a Windows 10 machine.
My local sound goes through an external audio device, a Steinberg UR22mkII audio interface (which enables me to use a professional microphone)
Unfortunately, so far I am able to either record outgoing sound or incoming sound, but not both simultaneously. (But see the "Puzzling" note below!)
When I set as recording source in Audacity "Line (Steinberg)", I get outgoing sound recorded only.
When I set as recording source in Audacity "Line (Steinberg) (loopback)", I get incoming sound recorded only.
I systematically tested all possible combinations of settings (also in Zoom where sound devices can be selected separately).
Puzzling: once it worked!
The puzzling thing is that a couple of days ago I somehow managed to get both sources (incoming and outgoing) recorded. I have no idea how that happened, but I do have the record (which helps me produce good team meeting inutes). Unfortunately I did not make screenshots of the settings in that meeting, and now I am not able to reproduce it.
Related question, but not the same:
Related question in Superuser, but with completely different software except for Audacity:
How to record both input and output audio simultaneously?
Additional tests done
After writing this question I did an additional test: In Windows --> Sounds I enabled the "Stereo Mix" option. This provides an additional (virtual) audio device to select from, so now I have in the microphone dropdown of Audacity not only "Microphone Array", "Line (Steinberg)", "Line (Steinberg) (loopback)", Speakers (Realtek) (loopback)" but also "Stereo Mix". I can select "Stereo Mix" as the source of sound to record, but unfortunately, Audacity does not record anything at all, neither incoming sounds nor outgoing sound.

Take a look at OBS Studio. It makes what you are trying to do very easy. You can add multiple audio inputs, outputs, and screen recordings. You can just add the audio source and your microphone to a Scene and hit record.

Welcome to Super User! Please read How do I recommend software for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Thank you! I will try this, perhaps it gives me a workaround. Anyway I would like to find a solution based on my existing software etc., as at least once it did record both outgoing and incoming sound (as described in the question).
